# Debian UnauthorizedAccessException for .NET application

Tags: debian, .net-core

I develop .NET apllication for Debian 8 (jessi) and i catch this exception (System.UnauthorizedAccessException, permissions Access to the path 
/usr/lib/myapplication/mydir/myfile.db denied).
Command chmod -R 0777 for mydir has been executed. There are no effectes.
Any ideas ?

**UPD:**  I'm using LiteDb library for creating lite.db local database.
Callstack:
System.UnauthorizedAccessException: Access to the path 
'path_to_litedb_file' is denied. ---> System.IO.IOException: Permission denied

at Interop.ThrowExceptionForIoErrno(ErrorInfo errorInfo, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
   at Interop.CheckIo[TSafeHandle](TSafeHandle handle, String path, Boolean isDirectory, Func`2 errorRewriter)
  at Microsoft.Win32.SafeHandles.SafeFileHandle.Open(String path, OpenFlags flags, Int32 mode) 
  at System.IO.UnixFileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, FileStream parent)
at System.IO.UnixFileSystem.Open(String fullPath, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, FileStream parent)
  at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options)
  at LiteDB.FileDiskService.CreateFileStream(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
  at LiteDB.FileDiskService.Initialize(Logger log, String password)
  at LiteDB.LiteEngine..ctor(IDiskService disk, String password, Nullable`1 timeout, Int32 cacheSize, Logger log)
  at LiteDB.LiteDatabase.<>c__DisplayClass11_0.<.ctor>b__0()
   at LiteDB.LazyLoad`1.get_Value()
   at LiteDB.LiteCollection`1.EnsureIndex(String field, Boolean unique)

Comment: What code are you using to read the file?

Comment: I'm trying to create it at first. For this action my code use LiteDb for making this action.

Answer (score 0):

I used wrong file  paths for configuring LiteDb database.
Issue was fixed.